# unable to catch protractor.promise.defer.reject

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, protractor

I am new to protractor. i would like to catch the exception from protractor.promise.defer.reject

```
var action = function(){
            var defer = protractor.promise.defer()
            ASYN_POST(function(result){
              if(result){
                defer.fulfill();
              }else{
                defer.reject(new Error('post failure'));
              }; 
            });
            return defer.promise;
          };
it('example', function(done){
   action().then(console.log).catch(function(){
        console.log('catch you');
   });
});
```

when the else branch is executed, catch function doesnot get called. how do I fix my code.  thanks

output:

```
 defer.reject(new Error('catch you'));
                         ^
Error: downgrading failure
    at Request._callback (/vagrant/vosaas438/spec/versions-api.spec.js:93:26)
    at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/request/request.js:199:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
```

Comment: Notice that you have a typo in your code: filfull();

Comment: fixed the typo. thanks

Comment: How often are you calling `action`? Notice that `defer` is an [implicitly global variable](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), which it definitely should not be.

Comment: yes. modify it to a local variable

Comment: after fixed the var, rerun again, defer.reject still can't be caught

Answer (score 0):

I also had troubles with .catch() . Try to provide second function to .then(callbackForSuccess, callbackForReject); it will be used as callback for reject as well.

```
it('example', function(done){
   action().then(console.log, function(){
        console.log('catch you');
   });
});
```